# How to select the filled values in the mysql cells

Tags: mysql, sql

What query should I write for selecting only filled cells? For example, in

```
SELECT DISTINCT  color FROM `products` WHERE category=4
```

I am getting the unfilled cells  also. What would be the query for retrieving only cells with values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add this to your `WHERE` clause:

```
and color is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly i we'd do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT  color FROM `products` WHERE category IS NOT NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT  color FROM `products`WHERE NOT (category <=> NULL);
```